# Spark 2 - Set specific "*-site.xml" or classpath from local using IntelliJ

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a Spark 2 job from my PC which is connected to a remote cluster.

If I put *hdfs/hive/core-site.xml* files into *resources* project path everything it's ok (they will be moved into *target/classes* path...), but I want to choose different version of configuration files at runtime.

I see that is possibile to set "Classpath entries", but i don't find the correct way to do it directly from code. I think that is possibile to add --driver-class-path options to spark-submit command, but I don't know how is possible using IntelliJ.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent configuration property for `--driver-class-path`  would be `spark.driver.extraClassPath`, which can be set by a SparkConf object